# Замена подстроки на многострочный контент

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Генерирую конфигурацию на ходу, требуется заменить вхождение `{{ namespace.default_ttl }}` на блок из нескольких строк:

```
stanza {
    storage a
    engine n
    ttl c
}
```

Блок валяется в соседнем файле и **не** может быть задан вручную с указанием `\n` вместо переносов строк.

Как это осуществить? В наличии есть sed и awk, хотелось бы обойтись без perl.

Comment: sed. переводы кареток пишите как `\n`. возможно обратные косые надо будет удвоить `\\n`

Comment: @Mike в том и дело, что я работаю с готовым текстом, в котором переводы кареток в обычном виде

Comment: Но текст для команды sed вы откуда брать будете ? я думал вы ее в каком нибудь скрипте руками напишите и все

Comment: @Mike из соседнего файла, который должен иметь возможность меняться от релиза к релизу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тестовый файл:

```
$ cat file
123{{ namespace.default_ttl }}456
```

применяем к нему небольшую программу на внутреннем языке программы *sed*:

```
$ sed -i 's/{{ namespace.default_ttl }}/\nstanza {\n\tstorage a\n\tengine n\n\tttl c\n}/' file
```

получаем в файле то, что требуется:

```
$ cat file
123
stanza {
    storage a
    engine n
    ttl c
}
456
```

---

### дополнение

если текст для подмены находится в отдельном файле:

```
$ cat pattern
stanza {
    storage a
    engine n
    ttl c
}
```

то его всего лишь следует прочитать, например, программой *cat* (используя модификатор `e` у команды `s` программы *sed*, позволяющий передать оболочке сформированную в *pattern space* команду и заменить *pattern space* её выводом). но если искомая подстрока «обрамлена» ещё каким-нибудь текстом, то потребутеся два «подхода» — сначала отделить подстроку от «обрамляющего» текста переводами строки:

```
$ sed -i 's/{{ namespace.default_ttl }}/\n&\n/' file
```

а затем заменить искомую подстроку содержимым файла `pattern`:

```
$ sed -i 's/{{ namespace.default_ttl }}/cat pattern/e' file
```

Comment: уточнил вопрос`

Comment: @Etki, дополнил ответ.

Comment: боюсь, sed все равно ругается на проблемный паттерн http://hastebin.com/towatilesa.bash -> `sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unterminated \`s' command`. В /etc/hosts слэшей нет, при замене управлюящего символа на @ та же ситуация.

Comment: @Etki, `$(команда)` там не нужна. просто `команда`

Comment: Ага, я подумал что это опечатка (плюс при первой попытке все проавлилось из-за слэшей в пути, с заменой управляющего символа все работает)

Comment: @Etki, кстати, можно и не менять символ-разделитель аргументов команды `s` — достаточно «заэскейпить» встречающиеся в тексте аргументов символы-разделители: `s/текст/замена\/с\/символами-разделителями / `